# Hide class one if class two does not exist on the page

Tags: css

In css, I have class 'current-cat-parent' and class 'hide-it'. One is on the top of page and 2nd is in mid of page. 
Now the thing is, I want to make appear 'hide-it' class's content only if class 'current-cat-parent' exist somewhere in the page, otherwise hide that content.
Please let me know how can make it possible
Thank you

Comment: You can do that with javascript. Search for javascript conditionals and hide/show methods. OR if you have some kind of DOM relationship between the 2 divs , you can use just CSS

Comment: Best thing to use here is JQuery - hasClass - you can read more here https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with Amir's answer is that the length of a div that exists on the page is `1` not `0`. Also `none` should be `"none"`

see below

```js
var parent = document.querySelectorAll('.current-cat-parent');
console.log(parent.length)

if (parent.length === 1) { // or > 0

  document.querySelector('.hide-it').style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.current-cat-parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: Red;
}

.hide-it {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="current-cat-parent">

</div>

<div class="hide-it">

</div>
```

Comment: Yeah,,,, It' working perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: @mukesh glad i could help.

Comment: oh ! sorry for this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
var parent = document.querySelectorAll('.current-cat-parent');
if(parent.length == 0){
  document.querySelector('.hide-it').style.display = none; 
}
```

Comment: Hi,
I have use
<script>
 var parent = document.querySelectorAll('.current-cat-parent');
if(parent.length == 0){
  document.querySelector('.hide-it').style.display = none; 
}
</script>

In head but not working

Comment: Use this in footer. @mukesh

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I tried in footer also but it's not working.. I am using WordPress. And this is for Archive page for custom post type

Comment: Do you have error in console of inspect element? @mukesh

Comment: I am really very very sorry. I don't know about Console of inspect element. <br>
When I add the code you gave, it appear in both case and don't hide.

Comment: Is your project online ? or on localhost? @mukesh

Comment: It's on local host. Mihai T gave answer below which is working. Thank you sooooo much for your effort. You are amazing. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If both of your HTML elements are sibling selectors, for example if you have something like below:

```
<div class="current-cat-parent">

</div>

---- other contents -----

<div class="hide-it">

</div>
```

Then you can simply achieve that using CSS only. Try this:

```
.hide-it {
  display: none;
}
.current-cat-parent ~ .hide-it {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it also through css.

.current-cat-parent .hideit{  display:none;   }

This code work when page has not current-cat-parent class

```
.hideit{     display:block;  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply but both classes are not at same place. One is on the top of page, and 2nd is mid of the page...

Comment: No matter wherever the classes are. My code will work try that.