# Hide html div conditionally using pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to hide `<p class="classC">Role C</p>` since there is no corresponding `<p class="classC">` in the first Text div. I am hoping this is possible using CSS only.

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .role .text:not(:has(.classC)) + .role-title {
                display: none;
            }
            body {
                color: black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="role">
            <div class="role-title">
                <p class="classA">Role A</p>
                <p class="classB">Role B</p>
                <p class="classC">Role C</p>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <p class="classA">content for Role A</p>
                <p class="classB">content for Role B</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Try this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49360410/4378314

Comment: Somehow I think you'd also want to use [HTML data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to pass a dynamic number into the css rule.

Comment: In the end most people go with JS on such a thing, and moreover not mix logic between JS and CSS in order to keep things separate. I suppose you have no choice if you're in a restricted environment without ability to do JS.

Comment: You are correct unfortunately I end up using JS. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS isn’t suited for such logic. You’re best to resort to a little JS and add a class of `.hide` to the element, and with `display: none;` in your styles.